# Data Extraction From Appian Cloud To SAS Database

Tags: database, sas, cloud, etl, appian

I have been extracting data from SVA_DELAY table in a CSV file daily and importing the file into SAS DB using ETL.
I want to automate this process. Is there any ETL tool or any other process I could follow to reduce the manual work?

Table structure/schema in SAS is the same as on Appian Cloud db.

I tried to use SAS ETL or SSIS but since Appian is a cloud service and on the web I am not able to create a connection between the two databases.

Comment: I don't understand what part of the process you need help with. Do you know how to make the CSV file? Does the structure of the cloud database change over time?  Or do you just need to define the SAS structure once?  If it does change do you know how to create a file that describes the table structure that you can use to automate the definition of the SAS dataset?

Comment: It seems like you can connect to the DB directly, if you're an Enterprise level customer. https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/23.1/Enhanced_Data_Pipeline_for_Appian_Cloud.html

Comment: Otherwise you can try Selenium or possibly IFTTT to automate some steps. If you can get the CSV file copied over, SAS can scan the folder on a schedule and read the latest file.

Comment: @Tom I am currently Exporting data in a CSV file from appian and placing it in the folder. From the the SSAS job picks the file. I am looking for a way to automate data from appian to SSAS directly in order to reduce the manual step to download/export the file from appian.